# Registering a Broadcast receiver for android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL and ask the user what to do?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I know how to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` that is notified a new outgoing call is starting.
I also know how to eventually drop the call and handle it within the application.

What I'd like to know is if it is reliable to ask the user whether to drop it or not?
As far as I know the application has a limited amount of time to return from the `RroadcastReceiver`.
How long is this time?

Have you ever implemented it?

**EDIT**

Trying implementing it I realize that there is a bigger problem. In a `BroadcastReceiver` you can't show a dialog. Form the doc:

> In particular, you may not show a dialog or bind to a service from
>   within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the
>   NotificationManager API. For the latter, you can use
>   `Context.startService()` to send a command to the service.

The reason is that you can't perform `AsyncTask`. I thought I was going to use signals to implement it but you can't do it because the broadcast-receiver is started in the main thread and you can't make it waiting...

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know the application has a limited amount of time to return from the BroadcastReceiver. How long is this time?

Formally this time is about 5 seconds - after 5 sec. while system main thread can't process system messages Android should throw ANR (Application Not Responding) dialog and force close your application.
More generaly - BroadcastReceiver `onReceive()` method should finish as soon as possible.

If you want show some UI elemets to the user, I think you should start your own `Activity` for that purpose.